# Android connecting MediaPlayer to VideoView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm working on an Android project where I have a VideoView and a dynamically created MediaPlayer object. I'm wondering, how can I connect my MediaPlayer (which it's prepared already) to VideoView Surface?

Thank you everyone in advanced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to bind your mediaplayer to a media controller, look at that first and then:

```
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
```

But be careful, this can only be donde after the view has been created and has dimensions, this will probably give an exception if you put this line in the app creation/resume flow: 
onCreate, onStart, onResume.

you can do it onWindowsFocusChanged().

Comment: I don't have any media-controller bind against the VideoView at the moment because I don't want user to be able to interact with it. If I need to use the mediaController, do I need to create a new one everytime for every mediaPlayer? If I do, will setting mediaPlayer = null also destruct the mediaPlayer?

Comment: First of all, a mediaplayer does not have any visual interface, it is an object to control media programmatically, it works along with the mediacontroller in order to have a view related to it. and the media controller is the user channel between your videoview and your mediaplayer

Comment: any good reference on how to do what you've mentioned? I want to make my mediaPlayer to show within an existing VideoView. Thank you in advanced

Comment: You can refer to this...
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778

And this:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-user-controls--mobile-22787

Of course it is for a music player but focus about the services creation and the mediacontroller.